# How can I increase the speed and performance of my implementation of an AI for Reversi?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I made an AI for Reversi, aka Othello (8×8), like Alpha Zero, using [this book](https://www.borndigital.co.jp/book/14383.html). This book is written in Japanese.  The source code of the AI I implemented can be found [in this Github repository](https://github.com/NL-User/Alpha-Ozero). There are comments written in Japanese, but there are also comments written in English. Check the master [branch's README file](https://github.com/NL-User/Alpha-Ozero) and source code on GitHub for more details.

I finished writing the code and I trained the model on Google Colab with a GPU. I stopped learning around the 3rd training cycle because it is very slow. I tried to rewrite to bitboard, but, it also very slow. So, how can I make my implementation faster or, in general, how can I improve my implementation, given that I have a limited amount or resources (including computing resources and money)?

Here are some ideas.

- Reduce the number of hidden layers (it can be weak)
- Rewrite the source code with Cython (it also run on Google Colab).
- Rewrite the source code in C++, and run on my PC with GPU.
- Increase the learning rate (it can do over-fitting)